# MySQL Apostrophe- How to escape and return correct results with MATCH/AGAINST

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a table sort of like this:

```
TABLE BOOKS
ID   TITLE             SUBTITLE
------------------------------------
1    Don't Forget      
2    Twenty/Twenty      How To Subtitle
3    Red Riding Hood    Another Subtitle
4    The Three Bears
5    The Threev Bears
```

MySQL is:

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE MATCH (titl, subt) AGAINST ('+don\'t*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

This Query is returning for me (in phpMyAdmin, I'm still not sure how to escape the apostrophe in PHP) the following:

```
   ID  TITLE
   -------------------------------
   1   Twenty/Twenty
   2   The Threev Bears
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting **"The Threev Bears"** and not **"The Three Bears"** too? Is "Three" an overlooked word?

Also why am I getting **"Twenty/Twenty"** but not **"Don't Forget"**? That is the only result I want from this.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a few questions in here so let me try to address them.

First, you are correct `three` is indeed an overlooked word. MySQL has, by default, a list of [ignored or "stop" words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) which aren't indexed. You can adjust this. The idea is to avoid cluttering your index with very common words that will return a large percentage of the results.

To escape characters in PHP you should really be using parameterized queries or at the very least using msql_real_escape_string. [Here's a great SO post on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

Finally, the reason you're getting `Twenty/Twenty`, but not `Don't forget` is because `Don't` is also a stopword. TwentyTwenty is matching on the `t*` I believe.

Comment: Thank you, I should've realised "don't" was also a stopword. Still investigating how to escape in PHP.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php  The best info there is on escaping sql strings in php.